# Animation Issue with size changing elements

Tags: xaml, windows-8

So...

I've got a listview containing several flag images 20 px apart(as spec'ed) . When the user selects a flag, the flag needs to 'get bigger by 2x' to show that it is selected . So I tried the following:

I edited the SelectedUnfocused state on the listview.
At first, I just created a scaletransform to zoom the flag. but the problem is that the zoom factor makes the flag overlap its neighbour. So I animated the width of the container to grow by a few pixels so that it can accomodate the size change, however this results in a jagger on quick selection changes.So I thought it is caused by the stackpanel inside the listview not being able to re-measure and layout the containers fast enough. I created a sizechanged event to invalidate and re-layout but no success. Any ideas on what I could try to force the itemspanel to continually re-measure during an animation?

A video of the behaviour
[here](http://sdrv.ms/121Meil)

Note thata the size of the image grows and overlaps a neighbour. only after the animation finishes do they re-layout

```
<VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
     <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
          <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
          <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
          <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
               <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
          </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterContainer">
               <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="108"/>
               <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="150"/>
          </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterContainer">
               <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="100"/>
               <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="400"/>
           </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
         </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
```

(I know that it is not traditional metro design and such but I'm following a spec)

Comment: Adding some relevant pieces of code to the question might help to get an answer.

Comment: I'll create small version of it and share shortly

Comment: Have you assigned the ScaleTransform to the container's `LayoutTransform` instead of its `RenderTransform`?

Comment: @Clemens: I put it in the rendertransform

Comment: Then try `LayoutTransform` instead. If it's ok, you may animate the ScaleTransform's ScaleX and ScaleY properties.

Comment: Hi clemens. I've added the layoutransform but I'm still struggling to get it to animate. it doesn't animate at all